Existence of Double Integral over a Rectangular Region with Discontinuities along Finite Curves
I can not find any "good" proof for existence of Double Integral over a rectangular region with discontinuities along finite curves. How can i show it? I tried to show the Sub Rectangles area that contain the curve y(x) multiplied by the sup(f(x,y)) and sum all of them should approach 0. but when i tried i get not get that it converged to 0 i get it converged to a specific number. i can not understand how to get total number of such rectangle that contain the curves. also i need it to prove the general double integral calculation method using fubini's theorem.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.
